# Zombie process using xlwings

Tags: xlwings

When I use xlwings to automate stuff in excel, I still have EXCEL zoombie process running even if I quit the application (with wb.Application(wb).quit()).

Thus, when I try to re open my excel file that bugs. I have to manually kill the excel application.

edit : I use the xlwings 0.7.0

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65199226/13968392

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `wb` is a global reference to your workbook which still exists even after executing the `quit` command. Excel sees that it is being referenced (through COM) and thus refuses to shut down properly.

For now, you can manually clean up your workbook object after quitting: `del wb`. In the next major release of xlwings, we'll also provide a new `Book.kill()` command that will get around this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will try soon ! An other issue. If I close a Workbook and open an other right after, sometimes I get an error. If we delay the open of the second Workbook (for instance with time.sleep(0.05) we could bypass the problem.

Comment: Can you please open an issue on GitHub, much easier than trying to resolve things in comments here...

Comment: This is old, but I didn't find any `Workbook.kill()` function and I get a bunch of zombie xlwings processes all the time.

Comment: `Workbook` has been renamed early on in `Book`, edited accordingly.