# Kill xlwings Python process on workbook close when using optimized connection

Tags: python, xlwings

I want to start using "optimized connection" feature of xlwings (v 0.11.4), but I would like to be able to kill Python process when I close the workbook (even if Excel instance is still running).
I couldn't find any information on this in topic in xlwings documentation.
Anyone had a similar problem and found a solution?

Comment: make sure you clean up your global excel object references: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37571308/918626

Comment: My problem is with Python process (not Excel zombie) running until I close Excel instance. It looks like this, I open Excel (Python process does not yet exist), then I open a workbook, which within its AutoOpen function calls Python to start the environment). I see a new Python process starting and being up entire time this Excel instance is running. This Python process will only end when I close Excel instance. I would like however to have the same result (end Python process) when I close the workbook (with Excel instance still running).

Comment: You can try to call the function `KillPy` which is part of the addin.

Answer (score 0):

The link below might be helpful where you can quit app directly (which will close and kill excel application).

[I cannot close Excel 2016 after executing a xlwings function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41089223/i-cannot-close-excel-2016-after-executing-a-xlwings-function)

Best Regards,
Python Beginner

Comment: Welcome to SO, please don't just post links as an anwser.